# How set transation isolation level programatically in Play framework 1.3.x?

Tags: java, playframework

I want to change the transaction isolation level just temporarily for a specific action, but not the entire application. How would I do this in the Play framework?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible out of the box. You can change the default isolation for all transactions in the configuration, but not single ones.

You can try to use something like this (**not tested**):

```
public void doSomething() {
    // (...)
    org.hibernate.Session session = JPA.em().unwrap(Session.class);
    int def = session.connection().getTransactionIsolation();
    session.connection().setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // Do your work. ex: session.persist(someUser);
    tx.commit();
    session.connection().setTransactionIsolation(def);       
}
```

Also there is the method `Session.doWork` which gives you a plain connection object, that you can use to create manual transactions/queries.